# Deployment descriptor in web.xml file is failing to load

Tags: eclipse, web-applications

I have a web-application that I'm developing using JSP. I'm running the application on Tomcat Server (version 8). In the project explorer view of Eclipse IDE, I'm getting an error saying that the source code could (a JSP file) not be run on server.

I have written my web.xml from scratch. It includes some server options or parameters which are defined by certain xml tags (display names). These display names were missing so I had to modify the web-app tag so that these tags are available. So far so good. The application is fine, but I get a pop-up message from the IDE giving a null pointer exception. I found that it is related to the Project View of Eclipse IDE, and when I switched to package explorer the error is gone but this time when I pick a server page to run on server (the server is running fine) i get another error which says the selection (the jsp file) could not be run on server. I believe this is still a dev environment problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have the stack traces for those problems? They'd be in the log file or Error Log view. Was this project created as a Dynamic Web Project?

Comment: There is no stack trace. In the error log view there are several items. First is the only error, An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for <projectname>". The others are just warnings, among which I found this relevant: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Service Temporarily Unavailable.